# class template that takes function template arguments that operate on an instance of the class being defining

Tags: c++

I would like to define a class template that takes function template arguments that operate on an instance of the class being defining.

Is this or something analogous possible?

I know that I could define conversion constructors, but for reasons not clear from this simplified example I want to be able to alter the functionality of the class with out changing its definition or creating derived types.

I know that I could include function pointer members and use setters to fix their functionality, but I would prefer to fix the functionality of the class using a declarative typedef rather than programmatically.

```
template 
    < typename T
    , MyClass<X> (to_X)(MyClass<T>)
    , MyClass<T> (from_X)(MyClass<X>)
    >
class MyClass {

    T value;

    MyClass(T v) : value(v) {}

    // is it possible to use to_X and from_X template args 
            // to declare member functions ...
}

MyClass<int> to_int(MyClass<std::string> value ) {

    // return result of conversion
}

MyClass<std::string> to_string(MyClass<int> value ) {

    // return result of conversion
}

MyClass<std::string, to_string, to_int> foo1 = 
        MyClass<std::string, to_string, to_int>("5");

MyClass<int, to_int, to_string> * foo2 = foo1.to_int();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a policy-classes approach: Your class template is parametrized with the two conversion policies

```
template<typename T,
         typename FROM,
         typename TO
        >
class MyClass
{
    FROM from_t_conversion;
    TO   to_t_conversion;

    MyClass() = default;

    template<typename U>
    operator U() const
    {
        return from_t_conversion( *this );
    }

    template<typename U>
    MyClass( const U& u ) : MyClass()
    {
        std::swap( *this , to_t_conversion( u ) );
    }
};
```

The point of this design is the type (form) of a conversion policy: A conversion policy could be any callable entity with the expected signature: A function, a functor, a lambda, etc.

**EDIT:** Here is an example of converters:

```
struct float_to_int
{
    MyClass<itn> operator()( const MyClass<float>& )
    {
        return MyClass<int>{};
    }
};

//A more generic conversion function:
template<typename T>
struct generic_to_converter
{
    template<typename U , typename X = T>
    MyClass<X> operator()( const MyCLass<U>& )
    {
        return /* something /*
    }
};
```

Comment: How do I enforce the overlapping typeness of the template arguments i.e. T=int and TO=int(string)

Comment: @user3666939 don't enforce it. Only pass a policy which works with T. Thats a common pattern, see the allocators of standard containers for example

Comment: can you please provide and example definition of FROM and TO. I am confused because I am not sure how I would define FROM or TO in terms of a MyClass<T, ?, ?>.

Comment: I am looking over std::Allocator and trying to understand how its disign is applicable btw. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't overthink this and keep it simple:

```
template <typename T, typename Converter>
class MyClass
{
    T value;
    Converter converter;

public:
    explicit MyClass(T const & v, Converter const & c = Converter())
    : value(v), converter(c)
    { }

    template <typename U, typename C = Converter>
    operator MyClass<U, C>() const
    {
        return converter.template convert<U, C>(*this);
    }
};
```

Your converter needs to look like this:

```
struct ExampleConverter
{
    template <typename U, typename C1, typename T, typename C2>
    MyClass<U, C1> convert(MyClass<T, C2> const &) const;
};
```

With a little bit more effort, you could take advantage of base class layout optimizations (in the same way that standard library implementations usually take care of allocators and comparators).

---

You could also have some rebind mechanic to allow the converter to be itself a template.

```
template <typename T, typename Converter = StandardConverter<T>>
class MyClass
{
    T value;
    Converter converter;

public:
    explicit MyClass(T const & v, Converter const & c = Converter())
    : value(v), converter(c)
    { }

    template <typename U,
              typename C = typename Converter::template rebind<U>::type>
    operator MyClass<U, C>() const
    {
        return converter.template convert<U, C>(*this);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct StandardConverter
{
    template <typename U, typename C>
    MyClass<U, C> convert(MyClass<T, StandardConverter<T>> const &) const;

    template <typename U> struct rebind { using type = StandardConverter<U>; };
};
```